# Location of .bashrc in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I made some changes in the `.bashrc` file some time ago. 
In which directory is this file supposed to be located exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your home directory:

```
# ls -la ~
```

Comment: omg. I did not find because I did not use -la on ls... Thanx!